# Python string in list condensing

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, edit

I am writing a program in python which generates a list of values and displays them in a game-board style format.
At this time, I can search any given location by x-y coordinates, index value or various other attributes.

for debugging, the board currently prints out like this:
Where "1" or "2" is a played piece.

```
1++++ 
++1++
++11+
+2+++
22+11
```

The indexed locations would appear like this:
01234
56789
1011121314
1516171819
2021222324

Right now I can list the index locations of each point, as well as the points surrounding it in the cardinal directions:

```
(0, [1, 5])
(7, [2, 8, 12, 6])
(12, [7, 13, 17, 11])
(13, [8, 14, 18, 12])
(16, [11, 17, 21, 15])
(20, [15, 21])
(21, [16, 22, 20])
(23, [18, 24, 22])
(24, [23, 19])
```

What I am attempting to create is a list of pieces that are next to each other in a single string. Through various methods, including enumeration and list manipulation, I have managed to get close.
This is the result I get:

```
[(7, 12), (12, 13), (16, 21), (20, 21), (23, 24)]
```

the result I am trying to get would be:

```
[(7, 12, 13), (16, 21, 20), (23, 24)]
```

My only restriction right now is I must use only inbuilt python resources for this project, I cannot import anything. How might I have python scan the list, find repeated values in it, (I know these are currently tuples, I have no difficulty changing it to an actual list), then combine only the ones that I need?

I can provide my code as needed.

Comment: Does your numeric data reflect your example game board?  If it does, can you explain it some more as I don't see how. If not, can you provide a clear example of inputs and the visualization of them as well as the outputs you expect?

Comment: Yeah, the numeric data reflects the indexing of the positions, where the indexposition is the location, like reading a book. (indexlocation, [surrounding locations]). I used an array to generate the board and using the index locations in a list made things much easier.

Comment: example: (0, [1, 5]) would be the top left corner of the board; while (20, [15, 21]) is the bottom left, and (24, [23, 19]) is the bottom right corner.